# Is there a reason to install Gradle instead of using gradlew?

Tags: gradle, gradlew

The recommended way to use Gradle is through the [Gradle Wrapper](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html), (`gradlew`), which is checked into version control of the project.

My question is: is there any reason to install Gradle myself from http://www.gradle.org/downloads instead of using the wrapper everywhere? (and copying the wrapper to new projects from an older project)

Answer (score 1):

If You work with gradle occasionally (not with one particular project (or a set of projects)) it's very useful to have gradle installed on command line. Then You can easily create a script and check if it works fine. With gradle installed on CL it's very easy and fast (no need to download the whole distribution every time). Beside this one particular use case nothing else comes to my head.

P.S. There's a great tool for gradle (and other tools) version management: [GVM](http://gvmtool.net/).